# Very basic graph theory clarification

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

By default, are two vertices in a graph allowed to have multiple edges connecting them, or does the graph specifically have to be classified as a multigraph in order for that to be true?

Here is the definition I am provided with by the Volume 2 book by AoPS:

> A **graph** is a set of points, some of which are connected together by lines. ... The points of a graph are called its **vertices**, while the lines are called **edges**.

I suppose I would like to know what the definition of a graph is within the context of competitions such as the AMC and AIME.

Comment: It really depends on how you have initially defined them but traditionally a graph that has multiple edges between the same pair of vertices is a multigraph.

Comment: To my knowledge by default a graph is allowed to have multiple edges connecting two vertices, when that's not the case you'd usually be told that the graph must be simple. When in doubt explicitly state what you're assuming and why is a pretty good rule to use in general tbh.

Comment: I understand now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I received and the knowledge I have gained in the past 6 months, a graph conventionally has at most 1 edge between any pair of vertices. Any graph with more than 1 such edge must be classified as a multigraph.

Comment: I would not rely on this convention in anything I wrote or read. It's an author's job to tell the reader right at the start about whether graphs can contain multiple edges between vertices.

Comment: Yeah, I'll keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: @EthanBolker Absolutely. The convention as to whether "graph" defaults to simple graph or multigraph not only varies from author to author, it has changed from one edition to the next of West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* if I remember right.

Comment: @bof do you know what the current edition of that book states?